# Error on Email sending workflow email on Sharepoint 2013 SP1

Tags: sharepoint, message

Environment:

- Sharepoint 2013 SP1 (Standalone) on WS2008R2
- Workflow Manager 1.0
- Active Directory on WS2008R2 and Exchange Server 2010 on WS2008R2

Steps:

1. Install Sharepoint 2013 (Non-SP1) and configure to send e-mail
2. Set Workflow Manager with HTTP connection
3. Open Sharepoint Designer, choose Sharepoint 2013 Workflow, add "send e-mail" action
4. Run Workflow and send e-mail successfully
5. **Upgraded Sharepoint 2013 SP1**
6. Run Workflow **and send e-mail fails**

We tried new install on SP2013SP1 but fails as same(SP2010 Workflow can send e-mail)

I have installed Fiddler and monitored HTTP message.

*Request Address :* POST /sites/test1/_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail HTTP/1.1

*Response Header :*  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

*Response Body :* 
error code=-2147024809, System.ArgumentException 
value=The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.

Parameter name: address

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: We answered by ourselves

Answer (score 2):

We found that setting "Central Administration" -> "Outgoing E-Mail Settings" -> "From Address" solved the problem.

Before SP1, it can be blank. But after SP1 it seems that it should not be blank.
I hope this helps somebody.